# SQL Concat Where Clause

Tags: php, mysql, sql

What is the better solution of this.

I have a function contain three optional parameters (businessunit_id,department_id,jobtitle). I have to build dynamic **WHERE** SQL clause according to receiving parameter.

**CODE**

```
public function getEmpSearchResult($businessunit_id,$department_id,$jobtitle)
{   
    $i=0;
    $WHERE = "";
    if (!empty($businessunit_id)) 
        {
            if($i==1)  {
                $WHERE = $WHERE." AND";
            }
           $WHERE = "businessunit_id"."=".$businessunit_id;
           $i=1;
        }

    if (!empty($department_id)) 
        {  if($i==1)  {
                $WHERE = $WHERE." AND";
            }
           $WHERE = $WHERE." department_id"."=".$department_id;
           $i=1;
        }

    if (!empty($jobtitle)) 
        { 
            if($i==1)  {
                $WHERE = $WHERE." AND";
            }  
           $WHERE = $WHERE." jobtitle_id"."=".$jobtitle;
           $i=1;
        }

    $query = "SELECT *  FROM `main_employees_summary` WHERE $WHERE ";
    $data = $db->query($query)->fetchAll();
    return $data;
```

In above code. To built **WHERE** condition I am concating **$WHERE** variable and using **$i** variable to track **AND** condition where required.

Is there is any optimized way to achieve this?

Comment: Collect to array, then `implode`

Comment: To add to ^, use prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there is any optimized way to achieve this?

I'm interpreting that as "easier to maintain, easier to read" rather than "performance optimised" - based on the context of your wider question.

This kind of code is 80% of the reason I encourage fellow programmers to look at using database abstraction libraries.  The cost in performance rarely outruns the benefit in code cleanliness.

It doesn't look like you're already using a PHP framework, so I'm guessing you may not already be using [`composer`](https://getcomposer.org).  I'd recommend looking at introducing it to your project, then using that to introduce data abstraction like [`doctrine`](http://www.doctrine-project.org) or [`eloquent`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent).

You'll find plenty of assistance on SO for using these libraries and tools.

`doctrine` brings you [`dbal`](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html), a library which sits between `doctrine` itself and `PDO`.

If `dbal` (or a higher-level library) is utilised, you begin to stop thinking about SQL (and injection protection etc) and start thinking about describing what you want from the database in readable PHP code.

For example: using their object-orientated interface, building extensive `where` clauses becomes a maintainable breeze (**warning**: code written from past memory, may not be *literally* correct):

```
$queryBuilder
    ->select('id', 'name')
    ->from('main_employees_summary');

if ($x) {
    $queryBuilder
        ->andWhere('businessunit_id = ?')
        ->setParameter(0, $businessunit_id);
}

if ($y) {
    $queryBuilder
        ->andWhere('department_id = ?')
        ->setParameter(0, $department_id);
}

// ... etc
```

Answer (score 0):

we can avoid the use $i as follows:

```
$WHERE = "";
if (!empty($businessunit_id))
{
   $WHERE .= "businessunit_id='{$businessunit_id}' AND ";
}

if (!empty($department_id))
{
    $WHERE .= "department_id='{$department_id}' AND ";
}

if (!empty($jobtitle))
{
    $WHERE .= "jobtitle_id='{$jobtitle}' AND ";
}
if ($WHERE) {
    $WHERE = preg_replace('/AND\s$/', '', $WHERE);//removing the last 'AND '
    $query = "SELECT *  FROM `main_employees_summary` WHERE $WHERE ";
    $data  = $db->query($query)->fetchAll();
}
return $data;
```

Or using array

```
$whereArr = array();
if (!empty($businessunit_id))
{
   $whereArr[] = "businessunit_id='{$businessunit_id}'";
}
//.......
if (!empty($whereArr)) {
    $WHERE = implode(' AND ', $whereArr);//joining with ' AND '
    $query = "SELECT *  FROM `main_employees_summary` WHERE $WHERE ";
    //.....
}
```